# How to clear persistent variables while keeping breakpoints in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, persistent

Is there a way to clear all persistent variables in MATLAB functions, while keeping the breakpoints in the corresponding function files?

```
clear all;
```

and

```
clear functions;
```

both kill the breakpoints.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, clearing persistent variables also clears breakpoints, but there is a workaround.

After setting the breakpoints you want to retain, use the `dbstatus` function to get a structure containing those breakpoints and then save that structure to a MAT file.  After clearing variables, you can then reload those variables by loading the MAT file and using dbstop.  Following is an example of performing this sequence of operations:

```
s=dbstatus;
save('myBreakpoints.mat', 's');
clear all
load('myBreakpoints.mat');
dbstop(s);
```

Comment: Note that until Matlab 2009b (I think), where they fixed the bug, the loaded breakpoints would not be visible in the editor - yet they were there.

Comment: @RTBarnard thanks for that solution. Unfortunately it doesn't work in @-folder classes because the files where the breakpoints are, must be on the search path, from which @-folders are excluded.

Comment: @Jonas my R2009b still has the bug

Comment: @Philipp: Ah, so it was in the release notes of 2010a that I saw that the bug was fixed.

Comment: The question is **why the heck** did they decide to delete the breakpoints too as `clear all` gets called? What did they think as they decided this. I really don't get it ..

Answer (score 10):

Building from RTBarnard's and Jonas's solutions, I came up with a script that avoids the need to save and load from a file.  Note, however, that this does not clear the classes like Jonas's solution.  I also close all the figures, since that's what I typically want to do when clearing everything.  Here it is:

```
% Close all figures including those with hidden handles
close all hidden;

% Store all the currently set breakpoints in a variable
temporaryBreakpointData=dbstatus('-completenames');

% Clear functions and their persistent variables (also clears breakpoints 
% set in functions)
clear functions;

% Restore the previously set breakpoints
dbstop(temporaryBreakpointData);

% Clear global variables
clear global;

% Clear variables (including the temporary one used to store breakpoints)
clear variables;
```

This script and some other Matlab utilities are on Github [here](https://github.com/ctnodnarb/matlab-utilities).

Comment: Much better to keep the breakpoints in memory instead of writing a file.

Comment: This would be my preferred answer. Thank you for the script!

Comment: @ndj No problem.  I still use this script all the time when working in Matlab.  The only other one I've written that comes close in usefulness is one that exports figures to vector pdf files with a specified size and with all the extra white space cropped off.  And that one's only useful because I use LaTeX a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If there is data in @directories, you can still use the method that [RTBarnard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514911/how-to-clear-persistent-variables-while-keeping-breakpoints-in-matlab/2515033#2515033) proposes

```
s=dbstatus('-completenames');
save('myBreakpoints.mat','s');
%# if you're clearing, you may as well just clear everything
%# note that if there is stuff stored inside figures (e.g. as callbacks), not all of 
%# it may be removed, so you may have to 'close all' as well
clear classes 
load('myBreakpoints.mat')
dbstop(s);

%# do some cleanup
clear s
delete('myBreakpoints.mat')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s=dbstatus; % keep breakpoints
evalin('base','clear classes')
dbstop(s);
```

To be copied in a function file (example myclearclasses)
This way no need for temporary .mat file.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you should use * as regexp to find all variables. It'll clean whole workspace and breakpoints'll exist.

```
clear *;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a quick solution for this using [preferences](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setpref.html) and the others' answers:

```
setpref('user', 'breakpointBackup', dbstatus('-completenames'));
clear all;
clear import;
clear java;
dbstop(getpref('user', 'breakpointBackup'));
```

The advantage of this approach is it's very clean (i.e. no temporary file) and clears everything.